# Transformation from skewed to symmetric distribution

Tags: normal-distribution, data-transformation, random-variable, random-generation

Let us consider a positive valued random variable $X$ which is following a positively skewed probability distribution.

Is it possible to a get a function $f$ (one-to-one) for which $f(X)$ follow a symmetric distribution?

Comment: You could apply the inverse CDF of Y to obtain a uniformly distributed randdom variable and then apply any symmetric CDF. Assuming continuity this should be one-to-one.

Comment: @InfiniteVariance. How  we can prove: any symmetric CDF composed of inverse CDF to X is gives a symmetric distribution?

Comment: Once you have the $U[0,1]$ r.v. you could also easily make it symmetric by shifting it by $1/2$ to the left.

Comment: Maybe you should specify to which reference point you wish symmetry (zero, mean (which I had in mind), etc.). The proof should be straightforward: The resulting r.v. will have exactly the CDF you imply, so if this is symmetric you are good to go.

Comment: @InfiniteVariance. Thank you. I got the point. The point of symmetry I am looking for is the mean.

Comment: @Janak: in this case you won't even need to shift the U[0,1] variable, and as long as you CDF has a mean, it will be symmetric about it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are some interesting special cases. Think of the log-normal distribution, which satisfies your conditions on $X$, and can be transformed into a symmetric normal distribution via the one-to-one transformation $\ln$.

Comment: This special case is fine, but I am trying to find the transformation in general case. The log transformation of my data is seems to be not following normal   distribution.

Comment: Indeed, one should not expect that a log-transformation would work in general!